# how to send Cloudwatch logs via email

Tags: logging, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codebuild

I'm working with *aws codebuild* and *aws codepipeline*.

In case the stage of aws codebuild failed I want to send the details via email.

Is it possible to send the cloudwatch logs via email?

Answer (score 1):

CodeBuild emits CloudWatch events when builds succeed or fail. You can use a combination of CloudWatch events, Lambda, and SES (Simple Email Service), to accomplish this:

- Create a new CloudWatch rule:

  - `CodeBuild` > `Build State Change` > `Specific state(s)` > `FAILED`
- Add a custom Lambda function target to the rule:

  - This function should call [`BatchGetBuilds`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetBuilds.html) with the failed build ARN, and use the `logs` information in the response to download the CloudWatch logs for the build.
  - Once the logs are downloaded, you can use SES to mail them to yourself.

For more information, see the [sample on using CloudWatch Events with CodeBuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-build-notifications.html), or [this one on sending emails with Amazon SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/examples-send-using-sdk.html).